# Tektronix TBS 2000 oscilloscope to Python

Tags: oscilloscope, interface, python, windows

I am a total beginner when it comes to communicating to your electronic devices using python.

I installed PyVISA, Open Choice Talker Listner (Tektronix), a few other items.

I was able to send basic commands to TBS2000 series oscilloscope using "Open Choice Talker Listner" as shown in the image below.

I was googling 'how to control your oscilloscope using python' but have not been successful so far.

I use Anaconda.

I guess there's plenty of information available online but for a beginner like myself, its been posing a huge mountain to climb.

Would anyone be so kind as to point me in the right direction of where to find such information, and maybe even post a simple script as an example?

[image]

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/PyTektronixScope/

Comment: You got IDN working. Are you sure the USB device connected to the scope is working? The scope might not support long filenames.

Comment: Also, you have a space in front of the USB0, try without it, and try without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The interface is called VISA

> Virtual instrument software architecture, commonly known as VISA, is a
> widely used I/O API in the test and measurement (T&M) industry for
> communicating with instruments from a computer. VISA is an industry
> standard implemented by several T&M companies, such as, Anritsu,
> Bustec, Keysight Technologies, Kikusui, National Instruments, Rohde &
> Schwarz, and Tektronix.
>
> The VISA standard[1](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) includes specifications for communication with
> resources (usually, but not always, instruments) over T&M-specific I/O
> interfaces such as GPIB and VXI. There are also some specifications
> for T&M-specific protocols over PC-standard I/O, such as HiSLIP[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_instrument_software_architecture) or
> VXI-11[3](https://www.tek.com/oscilloscope/tbs2000-basic-oscilloscope-manual/tbs2000-series-2) (over TCP/IP) and USBTMC[4] (over USB).
>
> The VISA library has standardized the presentation of its operations
> over several software reuse mechanisms, including through a C API
> exposed from Windows DLL, visa32.dll, over the Microsoft COM
> technology, and through a .NET API. Although there are several VISA
> vendors and implementations, applications written against VISA are
> (nominally) vendor-interchangeable thanks to the standardization of
> VISA's presentation and operations/capabilities. Implementations from
> specific vendors[specify] are also available for less common
> programming languages[specify] and software reuse technologies.

Source: [wikipedia VISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_instrument_software_architecture)

There is a python [package available to use VISA](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), whether it works for your scope is another matter.

You'll also need the user manual for [TPS2000 series](https://www.tek.com/oscilloscope/tbs2000-basic-oscilloscope-manual/tbs2000-series-2)

Use the talker listener app to find the right sequence of commands. Once you have find the right sequence, then you can use the "send function" in python to send the commands (usually a string).

Another thing is it can be difficult to set up the visa interface and get it talking so use a command you know to write an example script so you know that you're talking to the scope once you're talking to it you can send it then you command and then work your commands out

Answer (score 1):

VISA is just a low-level method of communicating with test-equipment, using commands that roughly correspond to the front-panel controls. So for example, you can set the sensitivity of channel 1 in volts per division, and this is equivalent to turning the front-panel control for that setting.

So VISA programs typically contain a lot of statements to set the instrument up, just in case they are incorrect, e.g. horizontal scale & vertical sensitivity, trigger settings etc. However, if you want to start simply, you don't have to do that; you do most of the settings manually on the front-panel.

Having set the instrument up, you'll want to get some data in, and this can get complicated; you have to check whether the scope has triggered or not, and issue a command to read the data. Unlike the settings (which are largely write-only, if you may assume the instrument is happy with what you've sent) this involves parsing messages from the scope, which can get a bit tricky - hopefully the library you are using will assist in this. Also you need to understand the actual data format, which isn't always obvious, as it can be in inconvenient hardware-based units.

With regard to the specifics for your scope, although the VISA commands for oscilloscopes are all broadly similar, they do differ in the fine details, so you need to study the programming manual for your specific device.